# AWS Data Pipeline: how to add steps other than data nodes and activities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

**EDIT**

What I'm really asking here, is whether most folks use the "Architect" GUI to build their pipelines, or whether most folks just use JSON. Is JSON the only way to access some functionality?

**/EDIT**

I'm just getting started in AWS, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

I've used the template for "Load S3 Data into RDS MySQL table" to create a basic pipeline that does a very simple insert:

[image]

For learning purposes I want to recreate that pipeline from scratch, but I can't figure out how to add anything to the pipeline that isn't an activity or a data node. Does this have to be done through the CLI? When I try to use the "Add" button in Architect I only see options for activities and data nodes.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to explain if you can specifically say what you want to add other than Activity or Datanode!

Comment: @franklinsijo - How would I add an RdsDatabase step?

Comment: Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TaskRunners, Preconditions, Databases, Actions and Resources can be added to the Pipeline only from their respective Activities and Datanodes.

For example, An `RDSDatabase` can be added to the Pipeline from  `SqlActivity` or `SqlDataNode` or `MySqlDataNode`.

**Add** `SqlActivity` **--** **Choose** `Database` **--** `Create new: Database` **:** Adds a Database object to the Pipeline.

[image]

`Database` **--** **Choose** `Type` **--** `Select type: RDSDatabase`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.